# How to construct PickVisualMediaRequest for ActivityResultLauncher

Tags: java, android, kotlin, activity-result-api, activityresultcontracts

I am trying to use the [Activity Result APIs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result) to handle the picking of a single photo for an app I am developing. I am trying to use one of the predefined contracts to keep things simple. So, I am attempting to use the [ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia) contract.

I am setting the Activity Result Launcher up as follows:

```
private ActivityResultLauncher<PickVisualMediaRequest> pickVisualMediaActivityResultLauncher;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    pickVisualMediaActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia(),
            this::onPickVisualMediaActivityResult
    );
}
```

And I am attempting to construct a [PickVisualMediaRequest](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/PickVisualMediaRequest) and launch the Activity Result Launcher here:

```
private void onSelectNewPhotoButtonClick() {
    PickVisualMediaRequest request = new PickVisualMediaRequest.Builder()
            .setMediaType(new ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia.ImageOnly())
            .build();
    pickVisualMediaActivityResultLauncher.launch(request);
}
```

Issue is that Android Studio is complaining about ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia.ImageOnly() not having proper visibility to be used, even though it is a valid VisualMediaType and the docs imply that it should be used this way:
[image]

I can't really find any code samples on this particular scenario. Am I missing something? Does the API have a visibility defect or am I just dumb today?

Comment: `ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia.ImageOnly` is a Kotlin `object`, not a class. In Kotlin, you would refer to that object simply as `ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia.ImageOnly`. I forget how the JVM interop works for these. Regardless, you do not create an instance of `ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia.ImageOnly`, but use the pre-existing singleton instance.

Comment: The Java equivalent would be ```ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia.ImageOnly.INSTANCE```. Writing it out this way in Java requires casting it to ```VisualMediaType```. After doing so in Java, the compiler complains about it being an incompatible cast. It's especially weird because it doesn't complain about it when written that way in Kotlin. I even decompiled that same working Kotlin code into Java and then weirdly the compiler complains about it. Very weird.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After some help from CommonsWare, I determined that `setMediaType()` accepts a Kotlin object instance. So, the above bad function I had should be:

```
private void onSelectNewPhotoButtonClick() {
    ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia.VisualMediaType mediaType = (ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia.VisualMediaType) ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia.ImageOnly.INSTANCE;
    PickVisualMediaRequest request = new PickVisualMediaRequest.Builder()
            .setMediaType(mediaType)
            .build();
    pickVisualMediaActivityResultLauncher.launch(request);
}
```

Android Studio complains about the type casting, but the code does compile and work as expected. Very bizarre.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to somehow hide this error in Android Studio?

Comment: ```PickVisualMediaRequest request = new PickVisualMediaRequest.Builder()                     .setMediaType(ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia.ImageOnly.INSTANCE)                     .build(); ``` Casting is not required but the IDE still shows error.

Comment: have you found any other solution? ?

Comment: @GauravMandlik Update the dependency to androidx.activity:activity:1.7.0 and you should be good. They fixed the error with v1.7.0.

Comment: @GauravMandlik easiest solution to every new google libraries bugs is to wait up to 1-2 years until they fix it

Answer (score 3):

As of March 22, 2023. There is a fix just update [androidx.activity:activity](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/activity#1.7.0) to version 1.7.0.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I also got the same error but when I executed the code it was compiled and run and worked as expected.

you can refer to the code

pickMedia.launch(new PickVisualMediaRequest.Builder()                          .setMediaType(ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia.ImageOnly.INSTANCE)
.build());

visit to [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/photopicker#select-single-item)

Answer (score 0):

For me this code from [vendor (last sample)](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/photopicker#select-single-item) is working
*(but yep, the error is still bothering so I'd like to find stable solution as well).*

[image: SingleMimeType as an alternative to VisualMediaType]